# How do I parse \n in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get a string from user which contains escape characters like \n and others. But, after getting user input, when I try to print that exact string to standard output via print macro it prints literal \n instead of a newline.

Here's my code:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    let mut string = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut string);
    print!("{}", string);
    io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
}
```

Output:

```
~ ./main                                                                                 
are you working \n\n ???
are you working \n\n ???
```

Comment: `.replace("\\n", "\n")`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks for your response, that works; but if I wanna check for \t and other escape characters then I have chain .replace again and again and it doesn't feels good. Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `\n` in code, the compiler automatically converts that into an ASCII newline (0xA/10). When typing input to a program like this, that's not done, so you get two characters '\' and 'n'. If you want them to work, you need to convert them yourself (e.g. using `.replace` as [@Chayim Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884305/chayim-friedman) suggessted).

You could use e.g. `printf` to do:

```
~ ⵃ printf "abc\tdef\n" | hexdump
00000000  61 62 63 09 64 65 66 0a                           |abc.def.|
00000008
```

However, this won't work with `get_line`